# How long does Timer.schedule schedule for when delay is 0?

Tags: java, time, scheduling, undefined-behavior

In [`Timer.schedule(TimerTask task, long delay)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long%29), it says it will throw if `delay` is negative, but doesn't say anything about if `delay` is zero. What will happen? I tried on openjdk and it ran instantly. Is this behavior specified somewhere else, or is it undefined (e.g it means infinite on other implementations, or some implementations will do infinite sometimes and instant sometimes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a Timer in java is a Thread with a task queue. Items are ordered in the task queue by when they are supposed to fire. Tasks with a delay of 0 are supposed to fire immediately and thus go to top of queue. I believe the behavior you are seeing is expected and should be consistent cross platform and across different jdks

Answer (score 2):

From [the Java SE7 documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html):

> If delay is less than or equal to zero, the timer fires as soon as it is started

So the result you got is the expected behavior.